# Docker Compose "Ghost Containers"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to deploy an application combining a number of different images.

Using Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
Docker-compose 1.117

Primarily, I have

1. ZooKeeper
2. Kafka
3. MYSQLDb

I notice a strange problem where i could not start my application with docker-compose up due to port already being assigned. I then checked docker stats and saw that there were three containers named "test_ZooKeeper.1slehgaior"
"test_Kafka.kgjdorgsr"
"test_MYSQLDB.kgjdorgsr"

I have tried kill the containers, removing them and pruning the system. When ever I kill one of these containers, it instantly restarts and I cannot for the life of me determine where they are being created from!

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into your docker-compose.yaml I'm pretty sure you'll find a `restart:always` somewhere. If you want to correctly shut down a running docker container managed by docker-compose, one way is to use `docker-compose down` from the directory where your yaml sits.

More information on the subject:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Otherwise, you might try out to stop a single running container instead of killing it, which according to my memory tells docker not to restart it again, while a killed container looks to the service like it just has crashed. Not too sure about the last part though.

Comment: Hi Aarkon, Thanks for the heads up! I realised what i had done was start a stack using docker stack deploy rather than deploying through docker compose up. I had then moved the directories and this threw me off the scent!